# How to specify a fill color in RGB format in a node in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, rounded-corners

I am just trying to get a rounded corner box with some text in it. The text color will be white and the box will be filled with a particular color.

The preamble includes:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
matrix,shapes.symbols,plotmarks,decorations.markings,shadows}
```

The code I have used is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[drop shadow,fill=black,draw,rounded corners]
{\textcolor{white}{TEST}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I specify an arbitrary color (RGB values in a range of 0-255) in the fill option?

Also, am I using too advanced a tool (tikz) to do something simple (draw a rounded corner rectangle filled with a color and text of some other color)?

Comment: The HTML format is quite helpful, too: `\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FF7F00}` (see [my blog post](https://martin-thoma.com/colors-in-latex/) for examples)

Answer (score 171):

In answer to your first question - mixing colours in (say) RGB format - you could use the notation similar to that specified in the [`xcolor` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) [documentation](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf), since TikZ recognizes this. For example, mixing/sharing proportions of black green is obtained using

```
\node[...,fill=black,...]
\node[...,fill=black!60!green,...]
\node[...,fill=black!30!green,...]
\node[...,fill=green,...]
```

and displays

[image: Nodes with different colour fills (sharing between black and green)]

Or, if you're interested in mixing certain *quantities* of RGB colours, you can use a part-wise mix as follows:

```
\node[...,fill={rgb:red,4;green,2;yellow,1},...]
\node[...,fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,5},...]
\node[...,fill={rgb:orange,1;yellow,2;pink,5},...]
\node[...,fill={rgb:black,1;white,2},...]
```

which outputs

[image: Part-wise mix of colours]

For answering your second question - dealing with boxes - you can use the [`fancybox` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancybox) or even [`PStricks`](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/). Here is an example using the latter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \psset{fillstyle=solid,framearc=.3}
  \psframebox[fillcolor=red]{\textcolor{white}{TEST}}
  \psframebox[fillcolor=green!50!red]{\textcolor{white}{TEST}}
  \psframebox[fillcolor=black!50]{\textcolor{white}{TEST}}
  \psframebox[fillcolor={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}]{\textcolor{white}{TEST}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}​
```

[image: PStricks rounded/coloured boxes]

Comment: Cool, I didn't know before about the `rgb:...` syntax!

Comment: About the notation `rgb:red,4;green,2;yellow,1`, what are the units? Seems not to be percentage...

Comment: @kebs: I think the units are all converted to shares of the total (`red` + `green` + `yellow`; perhaps within some range, either [0,1] or [0,255]), since [this code](https://pastebin.com/RUNFV12c) produces [the same output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTxfc.png) for all `\psframebox`s.

Comment: Hmmmm... suspicious. `{rgb:red,1;green,1:blue,1}` seems to be some kind of subtractive mixing since I get an ugly brown and not white.

Comment: @JasonS Well, each of the three values is divided by the sum of all values, so you get `.333,.333,.333` in "standard" notation which is some darker gray. If you specify the divisor explicitly using `{rgb,1:red,1;green,1:blue,1}` you would get white.

Answer (score 143):

One approach is to predefine in the preamble all colors one wants to use, for instance

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{1,0.2,0.3}
```

with values in the interval (0,1) or

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{255,51,76}
```

with integer values in the range 0–255 (use a more sensible name than `mycolor`) and then `mycolor` can be used in all color specifications, for instance

```
\node[drop shadow,fill=mycolor,draw,rounded corners]
```

In this way you can control the colors and also change them just by modifying their definition.

Comment: It is also possible to define the colors right before you use them. You can even redefine them later if you want to use different values for them. I did that once when I was generating a plot with a lot of different colors in it. I have created a new answer for this alternative approach.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever I don't think that changing the meaning of a color name is a good way to proceed.

Comment: Why not? It will be like any other variable. Of course you shouldn't call the color "`red`" or something like that if you intend to change its value because you would expect that color to be constant, but if you call it "`mycolor`" or "`tempcolor`" I see no problem with it.

Comment: Notably this requires you to `\usepackage{xcolor}`

Answer (score 37):

Werner has shown the rgb-syntax to mix colors, egreg has shown how to define a color in RGB and then use it.
If you want to specify a color with RGB values [0-255] without defining it before, you can use the rgb-syntax Werner has shown by setting the optional div-parameter to 255 (see [xcolor package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf), pages 13 and 16).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz\node[rounded corners, fill={rgb,255:red,21; green,66; blue,128}, text=white, draw=black] {hello world};
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21):

Another approach, that builds on `egregs` answer, is to predefine the color one wants to use right before it is used. In that way one doesn't have to be so creative when coming up with the names for all colors, which is especially cumbersome if a lot of different colors have to be defined. The color can then be used in all color specifications (just like colors defined in the preamble), for instance

```
...
\definecolor{tempcolor}{rgb}{1,0.2,0.3}
\node[drop shadow,fill=tempcolor,draw,rounded corners]
...
```

with values in the interval (0,1) or

```
...
\definecolor{tempcolor}{RGB}{255,51,76}
\node[drop shadow,fill=tempcolor,draw,rounded corners]
...
```

with integer values in the range 0–255 (the name "tempcolor" is just a suggestion).

If you want to make sure you're not overriding any earlier defined color named `tempcolor`, you can always define the color in a separate scope:

```
...
{
    \definecolor{tempcolor}{rgb}{1,0.2,0.3}
    \node[drop shadow,fill=tempcolor,draw,rounded corners]
}
...
```