# set textcolor in tikzstyle

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles

How can I set text color inside tikzstyle? I tried as shown below, but surely that is not the correct thing.

I can do it seperately in each node, as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24434/how-to-specify-a-fill-color-in-rgb-format-in-a-node-in-tikzpicture), but I want to declare it globally.

```
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill={rgb:red,91;green,146;blue,230}, node distance=4cm, 
text width=5em, text centered, minimum height=2em, text color=white]
```

Comment: not directly relevant, but implicitly: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372)

Comment: Did you try with just `text=white`? Look at manual section `Text parameters: Color and opacity`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Although its 729 pages (1129 in last cvs) are intimidating, `TiKZ` manual provides a lot of useful information.

[image]