# TikZ: fill text color different than fill

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a simple circle with text. The text color is the same color as the fill.

I'd like the text color of the node to be black.

I am trying to use `\fill` alone rather than `\fill` and draw so I can get them in one line.

Comment: Not a duplicate but related: [set textcolor in tikzstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147582/set-textcolor-in-tikzstyle/147626#147626)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`text=...` your color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[fill=green, text=red, circle, draw=black] {With node};
        \draw[fill=cyan] (3,0) circle (1cm) node[text=blue] {With draw};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]