# Why does 'fill' before 'color' in TikZ node options make the whole node filled with the color set in 'color'?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

Here is my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[circle,color=yellow,fill=red,font=\Huge] at (0, 0) {foo};
\node[circle,fill=red,color=yellow,font=\Huge] at (3, 0) {foo};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

The second circle was supposed to show yellow text on red background. Why is completely yellow?

Comment: `color` sets all colors, most notable `text`, `draw` and `fill`. And pgfkeys uses the principle of overwriting previous keys.

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147582/set-textcolor-in-tikzstyle/147626#147626 and you'll see that the color of text in nodes is fixed with `text` option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code uses the `color` key. This is a shorthand (meta key) for most colors you could change, most notably `text`, `draw` and `fill`. You could even omit the `color=` part as it will be used by default.

Apart from the meaning of the key the order is very important as pgfkeys (which is used by TikZ) processes the keys in order and does not preserve values meaning that once you specify the key again (or in a meta key like `color`) it will be overwritten.

Hence the answer to your question: It is completely yellow, because you set text and fill color to yellow *after* you specified another color.