# How to globally change the color of tikz nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, nodes

I see here:

[How to specify a fill color in RGB format in a node in tikzpicture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24434/how-to-specify-a-fill-color-in-rgb-format-in-a-node-in-tikzpicture)

It is possible to change the color of a node locally. However, I would like to add a *background* color *globally* to all nodes by default. Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Are you looking for something lie `\tikzset{nodes={fill=blue}}`?

Comment: yes, thanks! almost though. I am looking to do it only for nodes that have a border. is there a way to detect it latex-programmatically in the tikzset?

Comment: It probably is but is a nontrivial enterprise. What is the ultimate goal of all this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible way. Please note that it is generally not recommended to globally set such styles. I do not offer anything of the sort "fill only nodes with a border" since this is too much of a hack, and I do not see why this would be better than defining a style `Draw/.style={draw=#1,fill=fillcolor}` and use this instead of draw. There is an `if` named `\iftikz@mode@draw`, but as you see it has `@` inside, which indicates "do not mess with that unless you absolutely need to". So, unless you provide a very good argument why this is preferable to the above `Draw` there is not much point IMHO to go this route. Anyway, here is how you could globally switch off and on fills.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{fillcolor}{RGB}{255,51,76}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{nodes={fill=fillcolor}} % switch on global settings

\tikz{\node[draw]{Hello};}

\tikz{\node{World};}

\colorlet{fillcolor}{green}
\tikz{\node{Duck};}

\tikz{\node{Koala};}

\tikzset{every node/.style={}} %switch off global settings

\tikz{\node{Squirrel};}

\end{document}
```

[image]