# Converting Windows Paint RGB color model to xcolor's

Tags: color

This question came up to me because I didn't want to define a new color in my LaTeX project.

I want to use a very specific color in my tikz drawing. Using [Microsoft Paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Paint)'s Color Picker tool, I get the following information about it:

[image: screenshot]

The values I obtained with the tool are shown in the right window inside the screenshot, reading

```
Hue: 205
Saturation: 67
Lum(?) 123
Red: 165
Green: 96
Blue: 157
```

So I went over to TeX to try `xcolor`'s color specification:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\texttt{red!64.7!green!37.64!blue!61.56!} \hfill \fcolorbox{black}{red!64.7!green!37.64!blue!61.56!}{\hspace{2mm}}
\end{document}
```

[image: xcolor result]

(the red color is 165/255=64.7% so this the value I gave to `red`, same for green and blue).

Looks close, doesn't it?

So I headed over again to Windows Paint to see if color picker gives the same color, as in the first pick, and it turns out that no:

```
Hue: 169
Saturation: 95
Lum(brightness?) 148
Red: 136
Green: 119
Blue: 196
```

[image: second trial]

If I am not wrong, one can specifty a color using the rgb model, or the hue, saturation,brightness model. Both differ in the cross check I made.

How can I get exactly the same color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a color by its RGB components directly in Ti*k*Z, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343680/38080 and use for example:

```
\tikz \fill [color={rgb,255:red,165;green,95;blue,157}] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
```

Alternatively, you can define a color or use a model directly: `RGB` is the model with red, blue, and green with range 0...255.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{165,95,157}
\begin{document}

{\color{mycolor}\vrule width 50pt height 20pt}

(Back to black)

{\color[RGB]{165,95,157}\vrule width 50pt height 20pt}

(Now with Ti\emph{k}Z):

\tikz \fill [color={rgb,255:red,165;green,95;blue,157}] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);

\end{document}
```

Here is the result, with a bit of the color picker window:
[image]

You can find a list of color-changing command in section 2.6 of the manual:

[image]

Your `!` command is a mix, used to blend colors; with

```
red!64.7!green!37.64!blue!61.56!
```

you are mixing  64.7% of red with green, *then mix the 37.64%  of the result* with  blue, and then mix *the 61.56% of the result* with white... See the manual at page 33 (thanks Steven B. Segletes! [I got that the other way around](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596268/converting-windows-paint-rgb-color-model-to-xcolors/596271?noredirect=1#comment1495258_596271)) :

[image]

which is useful when you want to make gradients or color-coded thing, given that it works with whatever color, like `mycolor1!50!mycolor2`.

Comment: Hmm.. Good to know! So what is the correct use of the `red!_!green!_!blue!_!`?

Comment: Still, is it possible to use the `red!_!green!_!blue!_!` to completely specify an rgb combination?

Comment: @tush, maybe, but you have to carry out the weights, because the mix is made progressively; so `red!50!blue!50!green` will have 25% red, 25% blue, and 50% green.

Comment: I understand. I will take the time in the next few days to make the calculation. If it is possible, and if I succeed, I will write down an answer here. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: ...and why you can't use the direct `\color[RGB]{50,50,50}` command? It seems a bit of gimmicky to use a blend when you want a mix...

Comment: Based on your explanation, `red!80!green` would be 80% green.  But methinks it is 80% red.  Thus, to my way of thinking, `red!50!blue!75!green` is 50% red, 37.5% blue and 12.5% green