# Specifying RGB colour literal for `tcolorbox` option

Tags: color, tcolorbox

The [documentation](https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) for `tcolorbox` suggests that the usual `xcolor` literals such as `red!75!black` can be used when specifying colour options.

However... **Is it possible to specify RGB colour literals without the intermediate use of `\definecolor` or `\colorlet`?**

The only way I've managed this so far is using:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    \definecolor{cellcolor}{rgb}{0.5,0.6,0.8}
    \tcbox[colback=cellcolor]{Some text}
\end{document}
```

Whereas I was *hoping* that something akin to the following would be possible:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    \tcbox[colback={[rgb]{0.5,0.6,0.8}}]{Some text}
\end{document}
```

For a single box this isn't an issue. However, where I'm intending to create multiple boxes with various interior fills, I can't help but wonder if there is an easier way!

I appreciate there are a couple of existing similar(-ish) questions, but I can't find anything for this particular issue.

Comment: `\tcbox[colback={rgb,1:red,0.5;green,0.6;blue,0.6}]{Some text}` will work (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343680/2388), but imho it is much better to define the colors first. This keeps such definitions in one place.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer... I note your point regarding defining colours up-front. However, for the intended use here, having them expressed as literals in this way is perfect for my needs. I also wish I'd spotted that section on extended colour expressions! If you put this as answer, you'd win the points!